# iostat showing wait queue when device is not 100% busy

Tags: performance, unix, solaris, iostat

I am on Solaris 11 and I am seeing the following
%w=32
%b=62

```
                extended device statistics
    r/s    w/s   kr/s   kw/s wait actv wsvc_t asvc_t  %w  %b device
   47.5 2564.6 1460.1 33481.8 62.1 93.0   23.8   35.6  **32  62** c0t60060E801054EB40056FD74400000015d0
```

From the doc

> %w  percent of time there are transactions waiting for service (queue
>   non-empty)
>
> %b  percent of time the disk is busy (transactions in
>   progress)

What does it means to have a device not being busy at 100% (%b=62) but still have 32% waiting queue.

I always thought there would be queue only if the device is 100% busy

I know I am wrong, but can someone shed some light on this

Thanks

Comment: May be your drive is bad. Check drive's SMART attributes.

Answer (score 2):

> I always thought there would be queue only if the device is 100% busy

The disk isn't *always* 100% busy.  Sometimes it hits 100%, sometimes it hits 0%.

Per [Solaris 11 `iostat` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1451/spmonitor-4.html):

```
r/s

    Reads per second
w/s

    Writes per second
kr/s

    Kbytes read per second
kw/s

    Kbytes written per second
wait

    Average number of transactions that are waiting for service (queue length)
actv

    Average number of transactions that are actively being serviced
svc_t

    Average service time, in milliseconds
%w

    Percentage of time that the queue is not empty
%b

    Percentage of time that the disk is busy
```

So

```
           extended device statistics
r/s    w/s   kr/s   kw/s wait actv wsvc_t asvc_t  %w  %b device
47.5 2564.6 1460.1 33481.8 62.1 93.0   23.8   35.6  32  62 c0t60060E801054EB40056FD74400000015d0
```

merely means the queue for this device had something in it 32% of the time.

How long is your sample time?

If this is the first line of output, it represents the disk statistics since the server was last rebooted.

Comment: if the disk is not 100% busy, why would there be a queue ?

Comment: @Noob Why are you assuming the disk was *never* 100% busy during the time represented by the `iostat` line?

Comment: because it show 62%b and 32%w.  So I am wondering if a device is not 100%busy, why is there a wait ?